# How to improve performance of setting HTML video currentTime in LitElement

Tags: html, html5-video, lit-element

*I am using a range input slider to capture user input:*

```
<input class="slider" type="range" oninput="change">
```

*There also is a video:*

```
<video class"output" src="video.mp4"></video>
```

*My JavaScript function `change` looks something like this:*

```
change(e){
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.output').currentTime = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.slider').value;
}
```

This works and I can control the video current time with the slider. However, it is quite laggy and performance isn't as good as I think it could be.
**Is there any smarter/more performant way of doing this?**

**Thanks!**

Comment: You should probably put your time updates in a requestAnimationFrame call instead of directly. However, default browser behavior isn't optimized for random seek - you probably won't have that part of the video preloaded. Might want to look around at a 3rd party library (hls.js, video.js) that does MSE extensions to be able to have everything ready. Lowering the bitrate of the video would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the elements on each input event is probably not very performant and should be done just once (ie in `firstUpdated()`). However if you don't have a specific reason for manually selecting the elements, consider using [lit-html bindings](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#binding-types) instead:

```js
import { LitElement, html, property, customElement } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-video')
export class MyVideo extends LitElement {
  @property() currentTime = 0;

  render() {
    return html`
      <video src="..." .currentTime=${this.currentTime}></video>
      <input type="range" @input=${e => this.currentTime = e.target.value}>
    `;
  }
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/u8ukge?file=my-video.ts).

Comment: Thanks, that made performance better. Still not great, but noticeably better.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Have you tried to play around with `<input>`'s `min`, `max` and `step`?